# git push recurse-submodules does not work

Tags: git, recursion, git-submodules

I just start to use git submodule, but the behavior is not as expected when push submodules recursively.

My git version is 2.26.2.dirty. My repo is simple, where root-project has one submodule 'common_misc'. I do some change in common_misc, add and commit it. Then go to parent directory and add/commit directory common_misc.

After all that, I run in parent directory:

> git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand

it will report error:

> % git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
>
> Pushing submodule
> 'common_misc' Everything up-to-date The following submodule paths
> contain changes that can not be found on any remote:   common_misc
>
> Please try
>
> git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
>
> or cd to the path and use
>
> git push
>
> to push them to a remote.
>
> fatal: Aborting.

Here is output of git status in parent and sub directories:

> % git status .
>
> On branch master
> Your branch is ahead of
> 'origin/master' by 1 commit.   (use "git push" to publish your local
> commits)
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean
>
> % cd common_misc
>
> % git status .
>
> On branch dev/test
> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev/test' by 1
> commit.   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

It shows both need be pushed.

I try to push without recursive in both parent and sub directories and that works without any problem.

Comment: That's an odd version to have (`.dirty`): it means someone built something that's not in any commit in the Git repository for Git. Maybe they introduced a submodule bug, or maybe it's in Git 2.26.2. That does seem like a bug though.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found what's going wrong.

The reason is, I am using 'master' branch in root project, but using 'dev/test' branch in submodule. When I run

```
git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
```

in root directory. It will push master branch in both root and submodule directories, although I set dev/test in .gitsubmodules. Having said that, when I cd submodule directory and run 'git push', it will simply push current branch (aka dev/test branch) to the remote repo.

I don't know whether this is a bug or feature. I'd like to see git team to improve it.

I don't see other thread encountering same issue as mine, so, just keep here as a record.

Comment: Oh my god, I've spent so many weeks troubleshooting this, and got nothing works. I didn't know that the branch name should have the same name as the root repo.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This should be better documented.

Answer (score 0):

Following your answer, one way to resolve this is would be to run :

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.SUBMODULE-NAME.branch BRANCH-NAME
```

This will add a **branch=** entry to your *.gitmodules* file, linking your submodule to the appropriate branch.

Note that SUBMODULE-NAME should be the same as the one described in *.gitmodules*.

```
[submodule "src/My-project/lib/my-submodule"]
path = src/My-project/lib/my-submodule
url = https://github.com/username/my-submodule
branch = dev
```

In that example SUBMODULE-NAME would be :
*src/My-project/lib/my-submodule*

and so, the full command would be:

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.src/My-project/lib/my-submodule.branch dev
```